# I am trying to run a script in -vx mode , but getting error

Tags: unix, ksh

**" ././tst.ksh: line 16: ONL  P  BL9_RATED_EVENT_D  1,295  780  4,063,232  60  LOCA  SYST  AUTO: cannot open [No such file or directory] "**

I am trying to execute the below script in -vx mode
I am not getting why in the output I am getting this

## !/bin/ksh -xv

```
    #for i in `cat /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log | grep ONL | column -t`
    while i= read -r line
    do
    echo $i
    stat=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f1`
    typ=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f2`
    tbs=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f3`
    tot=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f4`
    free=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f5`
    lrg=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f6`
    fr=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f7`
    Ext=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f8`
    All=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f9`
    spc=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f10`
    done < `cat /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log | grep ONL | column -t`
+ cat /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log | grep ONL | column -t+ cat /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log
+ column -t
+ grep ONL
././tst.ksh: line 16: ONL  P  BL9_RATED_EVENT_D  1,295  780  4,063,232  60  LOCA  SYST  AUTO: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues that I will explain here.
The read command files a variable that is given after the command. In your code, `line` is the name of the variable that is filled, and the `i =` doesn't belong here. The first improvement is:

```
while read -r i                           
do                                        
    echo $i                               
    stat=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f1`        
    typ=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f2`         
    tbs=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f3`         
    tot=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f4`         
    free=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f5`        
    lrg=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f6`         
    fr=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f7`          
    Ext=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f8`         
    All=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f9`         
    spc=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f10`        
done < /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log
```

I also changed the last line. The while loop wants to read from a file, not from the output of a command.
Note: You will get confused from Bash examples. When you want to redirect output of a command into a while loop, you can use some special syntax in Bash.
In Bash you will need that, so that the variables set in the while loop are known after finishing the while loop.
In your case, ksh, you can solve it by starting with your command and redirect it to the while loop.
Fixing your code without fixing the logic gives

```
cat /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log | grep ONL | column -t | while read -r i
do
    echo $i
    stat=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f1`
    typ=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f2`
    tbs=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f3`
    tot=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f4`
    free=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f5`
    lrg=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f6`
    fr=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f7`
    Ext=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f8`
    All=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f9`
    spc=`echo $i | cut -d" " -f10`
done
```

Using `column -t` did not help. You need to get fields seperated with one space before trying to split them on spaces. You need to replace tabs by spaces and multiple spaces squeezed to one space.
You can use `expand -1 | tr -s " "` for this.
I would like to suggest replacing the backtics with the notation `$(subcommand)`, but you can assign the variables with the read command.
My suggestion would be

```
grep ONL /tefnfs/tef/tools/tooladm/Users/Jithesh/prd3cust.log | expand -1 | tr -s " " |
while read -r stat typ tbs tot free lrg fr Ext All spc; do
        echo "Processed line starting with ${stat}"
done
```

Now you should do something in the while loop. The variables are changed everytime that the while loop processes the next line. After the while loop the variables are filled with the values from the last line processed.